# How do i arrange 3 numbers from biggest to smallest without using 5 if's

Tags: c#

i receive 3 numbers and i'm supposed to display them from biggest to smallest, i know how to do this with 5 if statements but i'm pretty sure there's a more efficient way to do this, i just don't know what it is.

```
int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (a > b) {
    if (a > c) { 
        Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", a, b, c); 
    }
    else { 
        Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}",c,a,b); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Any way you do it is efficient compared to the time spent waiting for user input.

Comment: @user2225104 I think OP means semantically/syntactically more efficient, not computationally more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple. Store the numbers in an array and sort the array:

```
var arr = new[] { a, b, c };
Array.Sort(arr);
Array.Reverse(arr);
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
```

You can also use the following (which is quite a bit faster, but also harder to understand if you're a beginner):

```
var arr = new[] { a, b, c };
Array.Sort(arr, new Comparison<int>((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x)));
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
```

In this case, you skip the call to `Array.Reverse` because you're passing in a custom `Comparison` delegate that specifies that the comparison should be reversed.

Answer (score 2):

You can put them into an array and use `Enumerable.OrderByDescending` + `String.Join`:

```
int[] ints = { a, b, c };
string ordered = string.Join(",", ints.OrderByDescending(i => i));
```

Comment: Originally, I stuck with simple `Array` methods since the OP seems like a beginner. But then I wondered about performance. Interesting Results: http://ideone.com/nIn86T

Comment: @JustinNiessner: since OP is a beginner he should not care about ticks but readable and maitainable code that doesn't break with two numbers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just do the `Math`

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", 
    Math.Max(a, Math.Max(b, c)),  // Get the biggest number
    Math.Max(a, Math.Min(b, c)),  // Get the middle number
    Math.Min(a, Math.Min(b, c))); // Get the smallest number
```

Posting this as an alternative to the other answers and original problem, but not necessarily the best or most efficient way to do it... :)

Answer (score 0):

What i would use is as simple as this :

```
var orderedValues = new [] {a, b, c}.ToList().OrderByDescending(value => value).ToList();
```

Comment: Out of interest why do you need the first `ToList()` call?

Comment: because on array you get the following error if you don't `System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'OrderByDescending' and no extension method 'OrderByDescending' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`